# Call controller function only once, Two div with same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on `angularjs`. I have two divs sharing same controller. My controller code is.

```
var app=angular.module('categoryPageApp', []);
app.controller('NgProducts', function($scope,UpdateService) {

   $scope.orderby=5;
   $scope.pageNumber=1;
   $scope.loadProducts=function($scope){
             //here goes ajax call
     };

 });
```

My two divs with same controller are

```
<div ng-app="categoryPageApp">
<div id="cat-products" ng-controller="NgProducts">
</div>
<div id="brand-filter" ng-controller="NgProducts">
</div>
</div>
```

As we can see, Now two times all variables will be declared and also update fucntion will be called.
I dont want this to happen as single time `http` call will do the work. Is there any workaround for this.

Also I want to build pager for my products using angular js . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried wrapping your objects in a single div, and using `ng-controller="NgProducts"` only once?

Comment: Actually two divs are partial view and cant wrap together, thats why i had to assign controllers separately.

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
<div ng-app="categoryPageApp" ng-controller="NgProducts">
    <div id="cat-products"></div>
    <div id="brand-filter"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store some flag after loading the products, something like this:

```
app.controller('NgProducts', function($scope,UpdateService) {
   if (!$scope.productsAreLoaded)
     $scope.orderby=5;
     $scope.pageNumber=1;
     $scope.loadProducts=function($scope){
        //here goes ajax call
        $scope.productsAreLoaded = true;
     };

});
```